# Page not Requesting video in Chrome

Tags: wordpress, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I run a small wordpress site on the side at http://www.thelittlebitfoundation.org/ and have encountered a strange bug with Chrome. The background video loop is not loading on first load on Chrome. Not as in it won't play, but according to the network monitor on Chrome, there is not even a request sent out for the video at http://www.thelittlebitfoundation.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/TLBF-2017-WEB-LOW.mp4.

The relevant html

```
<video height="100%" width="100%" src="http://www.thelittlebitfoundation.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/TLBF-2017-WEB-LOW.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
```

shows up just fine in the DOM but there is no request sent out for the src video.

Now here is where it gets particularly weird. If I refresh, it still doesn't load up. However, if I have developer tools open in Chrome and refresh, then the request gets sent out and the video plays as normal. I am not sure what is going on here and would appreciate any insight/help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. The response was being sent but the network monitor evidently doesn't pick that up if it is not open when the request is sent. Still not sure why it was working when refreshing with developer tools open...that is strange to say the least.

Anywho, the problem comes from Chrome's new autoplay policy. The video was loading but not autoplaying so it just looked like a black screen. The key was to add the 'muted' attribute to the html5 video tag. After that, the video conforms to Chrome's new autoplay policy and it started right up.